# Moneris - Proper Return URL Settings

Tags: post, paypal, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm setting up the Moneris eSelect Plus Payment System. Everything works except the return URL setting.

Using ColdFusion CF9, I'm passing data to the Moneris Hosted PayPage Configuration. All is working, but the return URL is not getting any data from Moneris.  I cannot seem to find anything on how it should be formatted.

I've chosen the Post method and also tried the Post with XML Method. This is the return URL setting:

```
https://pay.xxxxx.com/approved.cfm
```

I know I likely need to somehow pass the proper variables back as well, like orderID. Does anyone know the right return url coding? Should it be something like:

```
https://pay.xxxx.com/approve.cfm?orderid=(how do I pass the Moneris Variable Back)
```

I am having not having any luck with the Moneris Documentation or online searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh - I'm so upset with myself. The solution is easy. It is a Moneris setting. Instead of choosing Post or Post with XML, choose the GET option, and Moneris sends the appropriate variables to:

```
xxxxx.com/approved.cfm?response_order_id=x0b6ao&date_stamp=2016-03-26&etc...
```

I'm upset as I never tried that option, assuming it was a Post issue.